# How to write an APEX Trigger to override the default Primary Campaign Source on and Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create a trigger that will override the standard Primary Campaign Source association and put the first Campaign associated with a named Contact (based on a lookup field called Sourced_By__c) as the Primary Campaign Source instead. I am not receiving an error message but it is not populating the Primary Campaign Source. Can someone please assist?

```
  trigger VennSci_SetPrimaryCampaign on Opportunity (after insert) {

   // Make a List of Contact ID's.
    Set<Id> ContIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity OPP: Trigger.new) contIds.add(OPP.Sourced_by__c);

    // Fetch all the Campaign Members for these Contacts
    List<CampaignMember> cms= new List<CampaignMember>([
        select 
             id, contactid, campaignid,status
          from CampaignMember 
        where contactid = :contIds ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1

    ]);

    // Build a Map, keyed by ContId, of Lists of the related CM's
    Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>> cmMap = new Map<Id, List<CampaignMember>>();
    for (CampaignMember cm: cms) {
       if (cmMap.containsKey(cm.ContactId)) {

            List<CampaignMember> x;
            x = cmMap.get(cm.ContactId);
            x.add(cm);
            cmMap.put(cm.ContactId, x);
       } else {

            List<CampaignMember> tmp = new List<CampaignMember>();
            tmp.add(cm);
            cmMap.put(cm.ContactId, tmp);
       }
    }


List<Opportunity> OPP1 = new List<Opportunity>(); 
    if(stoprecurssion.runonce()){

   for(Opportunity newOpp: Trigger.new){

       if (cmMap.containsKey(NewOpp.Sourced_by__c)) {

           for (CampaignMember cm: cmMap.get(newOpp.Sourced_by__c)) {
                OPP1.add(
                     New Opportunity(
                        CampaignId = cm.CampaignId,
                        id=newOpp.id)


               );
          }
     }
   }
     if (! OPP1.isEmpty())  update OPP1;
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@IsTest (SeeAllData=true) private class VennSci_TEST_SetPrimaryCampaign{

    /* This is a basic test which simulates the primary positive case for the 
       insert method of an Opportunity. */

private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

// create an Account
Account acc=new Account(Name='test');
insert acc;                

 // create a Contact
        Contact cont = new Contact(
        Firstname='Jane',
        Lastname='Doe',
        AccountID= acc.Id

    );
    insert cont;

       // create the 1st Campaign
    Campaign c1 = new Campaign(
        name='Campaign 1',
        IsActive=true,
        StartDate=Date.newInstance(2014,01,01)
        );
    insert c1;

   // create the 2nd Campaign
    Campaign c2 = new Campaign(
        name='Campaign 2',
        IsActive=true,
        StartDate=Date.newInstance(2014,01,01)
        );
    insert c2;

    // create the ist Campaign Member
    Campaignmember cm1 = new CampaignMember(
        CampaignId=c1.Id,
        ContactID=cont.Id,
        Status='Sent'
             );
    insert cm1;

   // create the 2nd Campaign Member
    CampaignMember cm2 = new CampaignMember(
        CampaignId=c2.Id,
        ContactId=cont.Id,
        Status='Sent'
                );
    insert cm2;


    // create the opportunity
        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity(
        name='Test Opp 1',
        StageName = 'Closed Won',
        CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2014,01,01),
        Sourced_By__c = cont.Id 

    );
    insert opp1;


   }
   }
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. If I were you, I would add a System.debug call to list the content of each collection immediately after it is populated to see where the chain breaks down.

Comment: I have never used a debug Statement, I have added these lines in my code but when I check the Debug Logs after testing there isn't anything there. Am I not doing this correctly? "System.debug('SetPrimaryCampaignSourc - START');" is line 2 and "System.debug('SetPrimaryCampaignSourc - END');" after my insert call.

Comment: are you trying to insert new opportunities in the after trigger of the newly inserted Oppo? That is, if oppo A is inserted, create a second oppo B with campaign source set?  If not, your DML needs to be an Update DML

Comment: @Grace I think crop1645 is on the right track.

Comment: @Grace On the debugging, you can do say `System.debug('cmMap=' + cmMap);` (straight after cmMap has been populated) and that will output detail of the map content. One way to see that output is to go to the "Debug Logs" of "Setup" and add the User you are testing with as a New "Monitored User". The next 20 requests will produce debug log output that will be listed there (provided you refresh the page after each request).

Comment: Thanks Guys, you are correct, I was calling an insert instead of an update. I think this fixed it! Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Grace As crop1645's answer sounds like it fixed the problem you should click on the tick to mark the answer as accepted. He gets the deserved points reward then and others know that no more input is needed but can add alternate answers still if they wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
if (! OPP1.isEmpty())  insert OPP1;
```

Assuming when Oppo A is inserted, you want to default Oppo A's primary campaign source, the DML statement should be

```
if (! OPP1.isEmpty())  update OPP1;
```

and your construction of the OPP1 list should be (only set the id and the fields you need to update)

```
New Opportunity(    id = newOpp.id,
                    CampaignId = cm.CampaignId
                    )
```

BTW, this code fragment

```
if (cmMap.containsKey(cm.ContactId)) {

        List<CampaignMember> x;
        x = cmMap.get(cm.ContactId);
        x.add(cm);
        cmMap.put(cm.ContactId, x);
   } else {

        List<CampaignMember> tmp = new List<CampaignMember>();
        tmp.add(cm);
        cmMap.put(cm.ContactId, tmp);
   }
```

can be simplified to:

```
List<CampaignMember> workList = cmMap.containsKey(cm.ContactId) ? cmMap.get(cm.ContactId) : new List<CampaignMember>();
workList.add(cm);
cmMap.put(cm.contactId,workList);
```

Comment: Since you need to modify the Opportunity being inserted, this should be a `before insert` trigger, not `after insert`. Then you wouldn't need to re-update the record after you set `CampaignId`.

Comment: agreed presuming there was nothing else going on in the trigger that was updating other sobjects where the oppo id was needed -

Comment: All, thanks for the help on the trigger. That appears to be working now, but my test class is only returning 80% and I need to get it to 100%. I have added my test class above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Grace -- you can see what lines are not covered if using either Eclipse or Developer Console by looking at the test coverage details for your trigger. This will give you insight into where you need to enhance your test data to cover the remaining 20%.